Nextauth v5 middleware, redirect not changing the URL
I'm trying to implement an login -> onboarding -> payment page flow. For now I'm just trying to get my middleware to check whether there is an active subscription in a users group and if not, it should redirect to /payment. For some reason no matter what I try, the middleware will update the client webpage but doesn't update the url until the page is reloaded. So when a user logs in, it goes to dashboard, sees that there isn't an active subscription, so it shows the /payment page, but it doesn't change the URL (it's still /dashboard) until the user refreshes the page.
Here is my middleware, I'm using nextauth v5 (authjs) aswell.
import {
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  apiAuthPrefix,
  publicRoutes,
  authRoutes,
  groupRoutes,
} from "@/routes";
import { auth } from "@/auth";

export default auth(async (req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;

  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isGroupRoute = groupRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  // Skip middleware for API routes
  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return;
  }

  // Redirect from auth routes if logged in
  if (isAuthRoute) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
    }
    return;
  }

  // Handle protected routes when not logged in
  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    let redirectUrl = new URL("/auth/login", nextUrl);
    redirectUrl.searchParams.set("callbackUrl", nextUrl.pathname);
    return Response.redirect(redirectUrl);
  }

  // Check subscription for group routes
  if (isGroupRoute && isLoggedIn) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${nextUrl.origin}/api/subscription/check`, {
        headers: {
          cookie: req.headers.get("cookie") || "",
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Subscription check failed");
      }

      const { hasSubscription, needsGroup } = await response.json();

      if (needsGroup) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/join-group", nextUrl));
      }

      if (!hasSubscription) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL(`/payment`, nextUrl));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error checking subscription:", error);
      // Optionally redirect to error page
      return Response.redirect(new URL("/error", nextUrl));
    }
  }

  return;
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)",
    "/(api|trpc)(.*)",
  ],
};

My only workaround is to have my dashboard page check if there's a active subscription/group and if not then it shows a onboarding/payment modal.
